# cmake 'add_custom_command' to pre-process header files?

Tags: makefile, cmake, header-files, preprocessor

i'm working on a project requiring cmake.  i'd like to add some custom rules to my makefile, but can't quite get my head around how to do it.

both c source files and header files are in the same directory. also in this same directory are a number of `.def` files, which are the sources for some of the header files #included in the source during compilation.

if i were to do this in a makefile, i'd use a simple rule like

```
.SUFFIXES: .def

.def.h:
    $(PREPROC) $< > $@
```

how can i do this with cmake ??

i've tried various permutations of the following, both with and without cmake working directory specifications :

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT vvr_const.h
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND preproc vvr_const.def > vvr_const.h
    DEPENDS vvr_const.def
)

add_custom_target(vvr_const.h DEPENDS vvr_const.def)
```

but the header file isn't generated by the time the c source file is compiled, so the compile fails. i've also tried a variation where i replace the last line above with

```
set_property(SOURCE main.c APPEND PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS vvr_const.h)
```

in this case, the header file is correctly generated in advance, but `make` can't find it, and complains that there's no rule to make the target `.h`.

ideally this would be a general rule, like the `make` rule above, but i'm not opposed to making a separate rule for each of the `.def` files if that's what it takes.

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with the `add_custom_command` approach you present:

1. You did not specify a working directory; by default the command is run in the build directory, not in the source directory.
2. You rely on shell functionality here (the redirect to a file). Even though this probably still works. You should go with an approach that does not rely on the shell.

To solve issues 1 and 2 I recommend creating a seperate cmake script file receiving the absolute paths to input and output files and using those in the custom command. This allows you to use `execute_process` to specify the file to write without relying on the platform.

**preprocess_def.cmake**

```
# preprocess def file
# parameters INPUT_FILE and OUTPUT_FILE denote the file to use as source
# and the file to write the results to respectively

# use preproc tool to get data to write to the output file
execute_process(COMMAND preproc "${INPUT_FILE}"
                RESULT_VARIABLE _EXIT_CODE
                OUTPUT_FILE "${OUTPUT_FILE}")

if (_EXIT_CODE)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "An error occured when preprocessing the file ${INPUT_FILE}")
endif()
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(_INPUT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vvr_const.def")
set(_OUTPUT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vvr_const.h")

# not necessary to use build event here, if we mark the output file as generated
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${_OUTPUT_FILE}"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL}" -D "OUPUT_FILE=${_OUTPUT_FILE}" -D "INPUT_FILE=${_INPUT_FILE}" -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/preprocess_def.cmake"
    DEPENDS "${_INPUT_FILE}")

add_executable(my_target vvr_const.h ...)
set_source_files_properties(vvr_const.h PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)
```

Comment: thanks much for this, it seems to be the best approach. although i'd made several versions with directories, i'd [obviously] got them wrong, so your variables here made the difference, and your approach is understandable. thankyou. aside - the project is and always will be under unix, but even so, we're required to use cmake :(

Answer (score 0):

Documentation from cmake:

```
PRE_BUILD

    On Visual Studio Generators, run before any other rules are executed within the target. On other generators, run just before PRE_LINK commands.
```

So possibly your command is just running too late.