# Adding a library with CMake with generated source files

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

**tl;dr;**

When using ADD_LIBRARY in CMake it will check during `cmake ..` that all the source files exist. I have some that are generated during compile time. Is there a way to force CMake to ignore the missing files since they will exist when they are needed?

**Full version:**

I am trying to build Sqlite3 with CMake, and I can get it to compile, however, I need to comment out a few lines in CMake and run it, then uncomment them and run it again. I would like to do everything in one pass.

The main issue I'm having is that Sqlite3 using a code generator called "lemon". So to properly build everything, I need to compile lemon. Then I need to run lemon. Once lemon is done running there is a new file called "parse.c". "parse.c" needs to be included with the source to build sqlite3.

I will strip down the code to show the applicable bits.

```
set(SourceFiles
    #Lots of Files are here
    build/parse.c
    )

add_executable(lemon sqlite/tool/lemon.c)
add_custom_target(CreateParse ALL COMMAND 
    cp ../sqlite/tool/lempar.c . 
    && ./lemon -s ../sqlite/src/parse.y 
    && mv ../sqlite/src/parse.h . 
    && mv ../sqlite/src/parse.c . 
    && mv ../sqlite/src/parse.out .)
add_library(sqlite ${SourceFiles})

add_dependencies(CreateParse lemon)
add_dependencies(sqlite CreateParse)
```

So there are 3 steps that happen here:

1. The executable lemon is created.
2. lemon is used to create parse.c (among other things)
3. parse.c is compiled with a ton of other files to create the sqlite3 library.

With the add_dependencies this *should* work. But it doesn't. The reason it doesn't work is that build/parse.c doesn't exist on the first pass. I've been able to work around it by commenting out parse.c. After it is done half building. Then I can uncomment it and it will compile successfully.

I've looked into using ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND, which I believe will run lemon when `cmake ..` is run rather than `ninja` is run. However, when `cmake ..` is run, "lemon" doesn't exist yet so the custom command is unable to run.

**Edit 1**

So I came up with a hack...

```
execute_process(COMMAND touch ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/parse.c)
```

So when `cmake ..` is run it will create an empty file in the correct spot. However, there has to a be a better way. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)` to produce your file and then just list it in `add_library`. It will work out of the box.

Comment: @arrowd How do I make sure that the custom command is run after add_executable(lemon sqlite/tool/lemon.c) since it will fail until that file exists.

Comment: CMake will figure it automatically. Just use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_file.c` in the `add_executable`.

Comment: You may be able to adjust the approach presented in the last code snippet in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64736151/2991525 `add_custom_command` allows you to specify multiple commands and use the names of targets built in the current project btw; also I'd use `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rename ...` instead of `mv` to avoid the OS dependency.

Comment: @arrowd this not work if i want to glob generated files with regular expression